# Can you compare two DT_R8 values?

Tags: types, ssis, expression

In an SSIS package, there is an expression in a conditional split tranformation:

((DT_R8)DB_DURATION != (DT_R8)(ISNULL(SP_DURATION) ? 0.0 : SP_Duration))

Both the SP_DURATION and DB_DURATION columns are defined as DT_R8 coming into the conditional split tranformation.

When viewing the two columns in a data viewer, they both have the value 1.89

The expression above is determining that the two values are not equal.

Why/how are they not equal?

Answer (score 0):

I forwarded to data to a text file and noticed that the SP_DURATION was 1.889999999 but the DB_DURATION was 1.8900000001.  I then converted them both to NUMERIC(38,2) and the values matched.